# Al utilizar cualquier boton de la paginacion o filtro de busqueda de boostrap-table me desaparecen los registros , porque?

Tags: javascript, html5

Al meterme  y darle por ejemplo a la paginacion o a cualquier boton desaparece los datos de la tabla y no me deja filtrar o buscar o ordenar con los botones de los titulos.

nose si tiene que ver con que lo hago con el metodo ajax con el metodo post , pero no muestra en la parte inferior izquierda deon dice los registros que hay solo pone 0 todo el rato y darle a cualquier boton hace un reload de la tabla y borra los registros , pero actualizas y ya vuelven a meterse los registrao a la tabla.
aaaaaa

```
let dataTable;
let dataTableIsInitialized = false;

    $('#datatable_users').DataTable( {
        fixedColumns: true,
        fixedHeader: true,
        bSort: true,
        autoWidth: true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        lengthMenu: [[5,25, 50, -1], [5,25, 50, "All"]],
        info: true
     
        } );



const initDataTable = async () => {
    if (dataTableIsInitialized) {
        dataTable.destroy();
    }

    await listUsers();


    dataTableIsInitialized = true;
};

const listUsers = async () => {

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "obtenerReservas",
        data: {
            id_usuario: $("#id_usuario").val()
        }
    })
        .done(function (msg) {
            try {
                let content = ``;
                msg.forEach((reserva, index) => {
                   
                    content += `
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center">${reserva.id_reserva}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">${reserva.nombre_reserva}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">Pista ${reserva.id_pista}</td>
                    <td class="text-center" >${reserva.fecha_reserva}</td> 
                    <td class="text-center">${reserva.descripcion_reserva}</td> 
                    
                    <td class="text-center">${reservaIcon}</td> 
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="borrarReserva(${reserva.id_reserva})"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>`;
                });
                tableBody_users.innerHTML = content;
            } catch (ex) {
                alert(ex);
            }
        }).fail(function () {
            alert('Fail');
        });

    
};
```

```html
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
                  
                    <table id="datatable_users" class="table table-striped ">
                        <thead class="table-dark">
                            <tr>
                                <th class="centered">ID Reserva</th>
                                <th class="centered">Nombre de reserva</th>
                                <th class="centered">Pista</th>
                                <th class="centered" >Fecha</th>
                                <th class="centered">Descripcion</th>
                                <th class="centered">Estado</th>
                                <th class="centered">Opciones</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="tableBody_users"></tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```